# yii load data from database base on $_GET

Tags: php, yii

I have a controller that has a display data from a database depending on the `?id=`, it works correctly. However, if you do not give any value id gets error

`error 400
Your request is invalid.`

My code:

```
    public function actionIndex($id)
        {
            // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
            // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'

           $this->pageTitle = 'Page';

                $criteria = new CDbCriteria(
                    array(
                        'condition' => 'name = :Name',
                        'params' => array(':Name' => $id),
//if $id is not defined then error

                    )
                );
            }
            $ModelPages = Pages::model()->findAll($criteria);
            $this->render('index',
                    array(
                        'Model' => $ModelPages,
                    )
                );
        }
```

I tried this out in such a way, but it did not help.

```
public function actionIndex($id)
    {
        // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'

       $this->pageTitle = 'Page';

       if(empty($id)){
           $criteria = new CDbCriteria(
               array(
                   'condition' => 'name = :Name',
                   'params' => array(':Name' => 'index'),
               )
           );
       }
        else {

            $criteria = new CDbCriteria(
                array(
                    'condition' => 'name = :Name',
                    'params' => array(':Name' => $id),
                )
            );


        }
        $ModelPages = Pages::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $this->render('index',
                array(
                    'Model' => $ModelPages,
                )
            );

    }
```

Is my solution is correct (safe) when it comes to displaying the content according to the site?

Comment: I've just edit an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solution is correct but better use [getQuery()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest/#getQuery-detail) method for fetching GET parameters and handle the  error if no pages found:

```
public function actionIndex($id='index') //Notice the default parameter value
{
   $id = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id', 'index') //if id GET parameter does not exist $id will be 'index'
   $criteria = new CDbCriteria(
        array(
            'condition' => 'name = :Name',
            'params' => array(':Name' => $id),
        )
   );
   $ModelPages = Pages::model()->findAll($criteria);

   if (empty($ModelPages)) {
       throw new CHttpExeption(404,'page not found');
   }

   $this->render('index',
        array(
            'Model' => $ModelPages,
        )
   );
}
```

Also if your action can not receive `id` parameter you should set default value for it (`actionIndex($id='index')`)

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this way

```
public function actionIndex($id)
    {
      if(isset($id) && $id>0)
      {
            $this->pageTitle = 'Page';
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria(
                array(
                    'condition' => 'name = :Name',
                    'params' => array(':Name' => $id),
                )
            );
           $ModelPages = Pages::model()->findAll($criteria);

           $this->render('index',
                array(
                    'Model' => $ModelPages,
                )
            );
    }else
         throw new CHttpException(404,'invalid request');
 }
```